# How can I use handbrake to extract a scene without re-encoding - keeping everything the same as the source?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing, handbrake

How can I use handbrake to extract a scene without re-encoding - keeping everything the same as the source?

I tried

```
handbrakeCLI.exe -i SourceFile.mkv -o OutputFile.mkv 
--start-at duration:60 --stop-at duration:120
```

However, it seems to be re-encoding the file. I want it to be the same as the original.

If not handbrake, can ffmpeg do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFmpeg can do this. I don't believe Handbrake can.

```
ffmpeg -ss 60 -t 60 -i source.mkv -c copy out.mkv
```

Comment: See also https://video.stackexchange.com/a/11972/5657 and docs at http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy